# Assigning values to a model dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I gave it a try but it did not worked.

I am having two grids and a button. Initially the second grid will remain empty and the first grid will have some records.. When I select a few records in the first grid and click on the button, then the second grid should get populated with the only the selected rows of first grid.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var getLocalStore = function() {
    return Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model: 'Company',
        data: Ext.grid.dummyData
    });
};

var getSelectedStore = function() {
    return Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model: 'Company'
    });
};

var sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');

var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'grid1',
    store: getSelectedStore(),
    columns: [
        {text: "Company", width: 200, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {text: "Price", renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
        {text: "Change", dataIndex: 'change'},
        {text: "% Change", dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
        {text: "Last Updated", width: 135, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
    ],
    columnLines: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Framed with Checkbox Selection and Horizontal Scrolling',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    renderTo: 'grid1'
});

var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'grid2',
    store: getLocalStore(),
    selModel: sm,
    columns: [
        {text: "Company", width: 200, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {text: "Price", renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
        {text: "Change", dataIndex: 'change'},
        {text: "% Change", dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
        {text: "Last Updated", width: 135, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
    ],
    columnLines: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Framed with Checkbox Selection and Horizontal Scrolling',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    renderTo: 'grid'
});  

Ext.widget('button', {
text: 'Click Me',   
renderTo: 'btn',
listeners: {
    click: function(this1, evnt, eOpts ){               
        var records = sm.getSelection();
        getSelectedStore().loadData(records,true);
        grid1.getView().refresh();
        /*Ext.each(records, function (record) {
            alert(record.get('company'));
        });*/
    }
}
});
```

Please let me what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are defining the functions `getSelectedStore` and `getLocalStore` which return *new store instances* when invoked. That way in your click handler you would be grabbing an empty store each time! Lose the function bit and just set variables like this:

```
var storeToSelectFrom = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'Company',
    data: someDataToChooseFrom
});

var storeToPutTo = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'Company'
});
```

Then, define your grids using those variables as the stores:

```
var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    store: storeToSelectFrom,
    selType: 'checkboxmodel'
    // rest of your configs
});

var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    store: storeToPutTo
    // rest of your configs
});
```

Then, create the button with a click handler:

```
Ext.widget('button', {
    handler: function (button, event) {
        var selected = grid1.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        grid2.getStore().add(selected);
    }
    // rest of your configs
});
```

Comment: Ok that works. IF I remove the function then the bit of code I wrote inside the button handler also works fine. Can you suggest which is the better way?

Comment: Calling `loadData` fires the refresh event so you may not need to manually refresh the grid view that way, but otherwise, the way you had that was just fine.

Comment: Now I am having a scenario where the second grid populated by the selected rows of the first grid will have some additional columns in the store model along with all the existing columns of the first grid store model. I am not sure how to achieve/approach this requirement. Please let me know about this.

Comment: Update your model to include the extra fields, but then only configure columns to display those fields in the second grid panel.